# Create view from two tables with different column names

Tags: mysql, view

Is there a way to create a view from two tables, where one of the columns is different among the two tables? The problem I am currently running into is that MYSQL is telling me that there is an `undefined index` - which makes perfect sense since, in half of the cases, the column won't exist.

Table Layout:

```
(post_rank_activity)
ID, post_id, ... date

(reply_rank_activity)
ID, rank_id, ... date
```

What I want the resulting view to look like:

```
ID | Post_id | Reply_id | Date
x       x         NULL      x
x      NULL         x        x
```

And the SQL:

```
$rankView = "Create or replace view userRank as (
select PRA.id, PRA.post_id, PRA.user_id, PRA.vote_up, PRA.rank_date
From post_rank_activity PRA)
union All
(select RRA.id, RRA.reply_id, RRA.user_id, RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank_date
from reply_rank_activity RRA)";
```

And the result I'm getting, instead of returning null, it's returning the value of "`reply_id`" for the "`post_id`" field and then shifting all of the other values over - see below:

```
ID | Post_id      | Reply_id     | Date
x       x             date val      x
x       reply val     date val      x
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the `(` around the second SELECT. They are not necessary.

Comment: Can you post more information about the structure of each table and the relationship between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unions must contain the same columns in the same order across all parts. You should explicitly select/declare the null columns in each part of the union:

```
SELECT PRA.id, PRA.post_id, NULL AS reply_id, PRA.user_id, PRA.vote_up, PRA.rank_date
FROM post_rank_activity PRA
UNION All
SELECT RRA.id, NULL AS post_id, RRA.reply_id, RRA.user_id, RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank_date
FROM reply_rank_activity RRA
```

Comment: Right on, learned something new with the null selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your query should look like

```
select PRA.id, PRA.post_id, null as Reply_id PRA.rank_date
From post_rank_activity PRA
union All
select RRA.id, null as post_id, RRA.reply_id, RRA.rank_date
from reply_rank_activity RRA
```

Comment: You two have the same correct answer - thank you. (He wrote it first so gonna have to do what's right :) ) +1 though